# Pick row(s) in data frame with many columns

Tags: python, dataframe

My goal is to pick row index(s), given row data.

For instance, if a row data, list `['Parrot', 'Captive','BIG',0,0]` is given,the answer should be `2` for my data frame below because the row data is located at index 2 row.

The problem is the number of columns are too many.

In this simple case, the number of columns is `5 (X1 ~ X5)`, though.

Is there a efficient way?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'X1': ['Falcon', 'Falcon', 'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                   'X2': ['Captive', 'Wild', 'Captive', 'Wild'],
                   'X3': ['BIG', 'SMALL', 'BIG', 'SMALL'],
                   'X4': [0,1,0,0],
                   'X5': [1,0,0,0]})
df
```

Comment: Can you share in your question : How you are expecting the output ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Output is the index number. For the above case, the output is 2. I've just edited question.

Answer (score 1):

```
df[(df.X1 == 'Parrot') & (df.X3 == 'BIG')].index[0]
```

will give you the 2 you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `all` function to make sure the row has all True boolean.

```
df[df.isin(['Parrot', 'Captive','BIG',0,0]).all(axis=1)].index

Int64Index([2], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: The thing is, you need to list out all the desired element you want into a list first, just like your example, so for this part, you may make a user input?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, I cann't help using explicit for-loop.

```
 tofind= ['Parrot', 'Captive','BIG',0,0]
df = pd.DataFrame({'X1': ['Falcon', 'Falcon', 'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                   'X2': ['Captive', 'Wild', 'Captive', 'Wild'],
                   'X3': ['BIG', 'SMALL', 'BIG', 'SMALL'],
                   'X4': [0,1,0,0],
                   'X5': [1,0,0,0]})

print(df)
mask = [True]*len(df)
# df[(df.X1 == 'Parrot') & (df.X3 == 'BIG')].index[0]
for i in range(0,5):
   print(list( df.iloc[:,i] == tofind[i]))
   mask= [a & b for a, b in zip(mask, list( df.iloc[:,i] == tofind[i]))]
print(mask)
df.loc[mask].index
```